# Отловить value в событии click или input в компоненте плагина vue-treeselect на disabled элементе

Tags: vue.js

в доке есть [список событий](https://vue-treeselect.js.org/#events)
однако когда на в дереве у элемента установлен isDisabled = true - события select и deselect не работают. 
событие @input="checkDisabled(this)" ничего не возвращает в метод checkDisabled

а очень хочется показать пользователю notification, почему же он не может выбрать этот элемент

пробовал @input="checkDisabled($event.target.value)" - так же не помогло

возможно я не верно понимаю?

> input (value, instanceId) Emitted after value changes.

дополнил:

вот вызов компонента

```
 <treeselect
        ref="treecat"
        v-model="categories_select"
        :multiple="true"
        :options="categories"
        :disable-branch-nodes="true"
        placeholder="Выбрать категории..."
        :allow-selecting-disabled-descendants="true"
        @input="checkDisabled(this)"
    />
```

метод checkDisabled просто печатает в консоль.

```
checkDisabled(obj) {
                console.log(obj)
            }
```

@click не работает. @input - в консоли печатает null

Updated. Добавил код в песочнице

https://jsfiddle.net/5fzjne0m/3/

основной смысл - дать пользователю выбирать только в одной родительской категории и задать ограничение на количество выбора. о чем и оповестить пользователя в дальнейшем.

Comment: @click="" работает? Нужен код

Comment: @ValeraKvip не работает. обновил вопрос.можно взять пример из доки, например https://vue-treeselect.js.org/#more-features для проверки. попробую в песочнице сделать, если получится.

Comment: печатает null, а что должен? А если так @input="checkDisabled()"?

Comment: @ValeraKvip, ну надеюсь должен хотя бы отдавать id. если просто checkDisabled то undefined. добавил ссылку на песочницу

Comment: Никак, можно JS-ом навесить  onclick или просто показывать сообщение что достигнут максимум рядом с деревом.

Comment: @ValeraKvip, ну по достижении трех я показываю warning. жаль, что нельзя. Спасибо.